# TensorFlow: How does it subtract the mean from certain columns?

Tags: tensorflow

I have some tensor like:

```python
[[1, 2, 2], [3, 4, 4], [4, 5, 6]]
```

How do I subtract the row-wise mean of certain columns from it?

For example, if my selected columns are the first and last one, then I want the result to be:

```python
[[-0.5, 2, 0.5], [-0.5, 4, 0.5], [-1, 5, 1]]
```

Comment: figured just converting to numpy arrays, performing the transofrmation there, and then transforming back works fine, but leaving this up because i'm curious how to do this in tensorflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to do it:

```python
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.convert_to_tensor([[1, 2, 2], [3, 4, 4],[4, 5, 6.]])
mask = np.ones_like(x)
mask[:, 1] = 0
# mask values: [[1., 0., 1.],
#               [1., 0., 1.],
#               [1., 0., 1.]]
means = tf.reduce_mean(tf.ragged.boolean_mask(x, mask=mask), axis=1)
# means: [1.5, 3.5, 5. ]
result = x - tf.transpose(means*mask.T)
# result: [[-0.5,  2. ,  0.5],
#          [-0.5,  4. ,  0.5],
#          [-1. ,  5. ,  1. ]]
```

A few points for explanation:

First, notice the `.` after the last *6* when creating x. Because there is now at least one float value in x, this will implicitly convert the tensor to a float tensor. If you don't do that, it is type int. This will later crash because the means are float type and TensorFlow will throw an error when subtracting float from int. (Of course you can convert the tensor to float in other ways too.)

When creating the mask, you set the rows/columns you don't want to consider as 0s. Then, you can compute the mean with a ragged boolean mask, which will hold the shape of x while using the mask to blank out the desired values.

After that, you can subtract the masked means from your values. Here you need to do a few transposes to fit the mask to the means and the masked means to the values. (*mask.T* is one way in NumPy to transpose an array.)